# Speedup querybuilder ( stringconcat ) in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, string, query-builder

I've made a function that builds a query to insert into mysql. The upload is blazing fast but for inserting longer values the building takes somewhat longer. Is there A way to speed up a function like this? Because I know that a loop in a loop takes a lot of time for higher amounts of data.

```
foreach (string[] st in dataToUpload)
{
    buildQuery += " ('";
    for (int i = 0; i < st.Length; i++)
    {
        buildQuery += st[i];
        if (i < st.Length - 1)
            buildQuery += "','";
    }

    buildQuery += "')";
    if (st != dataToUpload[dataToUpload.Count - 1])
        buildQuery += ",";
}
```

This is the query I would like to build for example;

```
string test = INSERT INTO test (test, test1, test2, test3) values
test = test + " " + buildquery;
```

so test will be

```sql
 INSERT INTO test (test, test1, test2, test3) 
     values ("testvalue1", "testvalue2" , "testvalue3" , "testvalue4"), 
            ("testvalue1", "testvalue2" , "testvalue3" , "testvalue4"),
```

I can work with INNODB and MYISAM and it's working on a centos server with a 6700k processor with 32gb ram.

So the main question is: How can I make the building of the query faster?

Comment: it depends on your pc hardware and query structure. show more details here

Comment: @reds I added it maybe you can do something with it now

Comment: When you profiled the app, what areas specifically were the slowest? did you try string builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use a StringBuilder which gets Initialized to the right size right from the beginning. This reduces reallocation of memory on every string append.

Assuming that dataToUpload is a List you can try this:

```
        // String Builder Initialization
        // Size is calculated by getting the length of all strings and add 3 for each (','). 
        // Additionally there are 6 chars for " ('" and "')," per array
        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder(dataToUpload.Sum(data => data.Sum(s => s.Length) + data.Length * 3) + 6);

        foreach (string[] st in dataToUpload)
        {
            build.Append(" ('" + string.Join<string>("','", st) + "'),");
        }

        buildQuery = build.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: I tried some other so solutions that were also faster than my solutions but your solution is by far the fastest

Comment: Good to hear :-). As I already mentioned in my answer: As we know the size of the string right from the start, we can initialize the StringBuilder to the right size. This reduces memory reallocation which is taking much time.

Comment: Thanks I understand why but I was not really familiar with a stringbuilder I did not hear the term before but I am gonna use it more often for sure. Its quite neat how you allocated the sum of the data so perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your `buildQuery` is a `String`. Try `StringBuilder` instead. It's probably the best way to do string concatenation.

Comment: Thomas posted the whole solution but you were right aswell

Answer (score 0):

Feels like need more information here, but I suppose your are building an insert statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```

So, perhaps the best way to not do a `for` inside a `foreach` is replacing the string[] in the foreach, for a string with the correct values. Something like this:

```
  var count = 0;
  foreach (string st in dataToUpload)
            {
                buildQuery += " ('" + st + "'") "
                if (count++!=0 )
                 buildQuery += ","

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
var count = dataToUpload.Count;
var i = 0;
foreach (string[] st in dataToUpload)
{
    buildQuery += " ('" + string.Join(",", st) + "')";

    if (i++ < count - 1)
        buildQuery += ",";
}
```

Instead of comparing the st with the contents of the dataToUpload, use an index variable to speed it up.
And string.Join is a good way to concatenate strings.

Comment: Wont this give an error because in the string.Join you call st and st is an array of strings

Comment: @Frits: Your Join parameters are wrong. It should be 'string.Join("','", st)'